# FFMPEG extract audio from video with an annoying sound at the end

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg

I'm using FFMPEG to Extract audio from an *.avi video file
This is the avi file format printed with ffprobe

> ffprobe 0.avi 
>   ffprobe version 2.8.4 Copyright (c) 2007-2015 the FFmpeg developers
>     built with gcc 4.8 (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04)
>     configuration: --disable-yasm
>     libavutil      54. 31.100 / 54. 31.100
>     libavcodec     56. 60.100 / 56. 60.100
>     libavformat    56. 40.101 / 56. 40.101
>     libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
>     libavfilter     5. 40.101 /  5. 40.101
>     libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
>     libswresample   1.  2.101 /  1.  2.101
>   Invalid UE golomb code <-- This line is red in console, it might be an error, but the video plays well
>       Last message repeated 2 times
>   Input #0, avi, from '0.avi':
>     Duration: 00:02:54.33, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1880 kb/s
>       Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (High) (H264 / 0x34363248), yuv420p, 1280x720, 1740 kb/s, 15 fps, 15 tbr, 15 tbn, 30 tbc
>       Stream #0:1: Audio: pcm_s16le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 8000 Hz, 1 channels, s16, 128 kb/s

I used ffmpeg command:

```
ffmpeg -i 0.avi -vn -c:a copy sound0.wav
```

Convert progress looks ok

> Output #0, wav, to 'sound0.wav':
>     Metadata:
>       ISFT            : Lavf56.40.101
>       Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_s16le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 8000 Hz, mono, 128 kb/s
>   Stream mapping:
>     Stream #0:1 -> #0:0 (copy)
>   Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
>   size=    2726kB time=00:02:54.49 bitrate= 128.0kbits/s    
>   video:0kB audio:2726kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB 
> muxing overhead: 0.002794%

Output sound information:

> Input #0, wav, from 'sound0.wav':
>     Metadata:
>       encoder         : Lavf56.40.101
>     Duration: 00:02:54.49, bitrate: 128 kb/s
>       Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_s16le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 8000 Hz, 1 
> channels, s16, 128 kb/s

Everything looks ok, but an annoying sounds (just a beep or something like that) comes to end at the audio output file while the input video is fine.

http://vocaroo.com/i/s00Ia5bO0JID

I don't have base knowledge working with Multimedia or ffmpeg, so I have no idea what happened.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Seems the stream copy is copying the entire stream, including the part which extends past the video duration.

Try

```
ffmpeg -i 0.avi -vn -c:a copy -t 02:54.33 sound0.wav
```

Comment: Thanks to Mulvya, -t argument temporarily works for me but look like I need to determine the video duration first (from bash script).
Is there any other way?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe that happens because of codec problems. The option `-c:a copy` copies Audio codec.

use `ffmpeg -i 0.avi -c:a libmp3lame sound0.mp3` for encoding your audio to mp3 format.